# How do I mount a sparse bundle from an NAS

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

I am in a bit of tight spot. I backed up my MacBook Pro using Time Machine onto my QNAP NAS before receiving a new MacBook Pro from my employer. Both were running Mojave. I have admin rights, but they are somehow limited. Note that the option to administer this computer has been greyed out.

[image]

Now, when I first got the computer, and I tried to access the backup stored on my NAS, I was able to mount the Time Machine backup drive in my finder and I was successfully able to drag a few smaller files from the backup folders to my new folder. But when I tried to drag my 40 GB Photos library file to my new computer, it would stop with an error code -50.
I can't remember the exact wording of the error but it was something like the operation can't be completed error code -50.

Now, I can't even mount the Time Machine backup drive on my finder.

Has the sparsebundle somehow been corrupted? 
Is my lack of complete rights on my new computer an issue?
Is there a different way to mount the backup drive?

Thank you. I hope I've provided enough information.

Comment: UPdate: I was able to just get it to briefly mount (appear in my finder) but then I get an error that says "No mountable file systems"

Comment: It looks like you do have admin rights - it is ticked.  You just can't remove them from yourself.  Can you edit your question with full description of the error code 50 from console.  It should give more detail (like shown [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5950860) even if doesn't have an answer)

Comment: I added the most information I had available.

Comment: The greyed out admin rights means this is the only admin account on the machine and its the admin account.  You must have one admin account with macOS. So, you cannot uncheck it.

Comment: How do I mount the sparsebundle? Or tell if it is corrupted?